# How to determine if a component property value is modified or not?

Tags: delphi, rtti, delphi-xe7

I am trying to write a function that should return whether or not a property value has changed for a component, or to put it better is no longer the `Default`. Delphi shows this from the Object Inspector (values become Bold) but that could well be down to the fact that properties and values are stored in the DFM.

So for example, I have a Button1 and the below caption value is unchanged:

> Caption = [Button1]

So the function should return True because it is unchanged and thus is the default. However if the caption is no longer the default, eg:

> Caption = [Button1WithNewCaption]

Then the function should return False.

---

I believe that RTTI is designed specifically for this type of requirement, but I lack knowledge in this area and cannot seem to figure out the solution. Below is what I tried so far which just causes Access Violation errors which is more than likely because I am not creating and implementing it correctly.

```
function ValueIsDefault(Component: TComponent; APropName: string): Boolean;
var
  IndexedProperty: TRTTIIndexedProperty;
begin
  IndexedProperty := TRttiContext.Create.GetType(Component).GetIndexedProperty(APropName);
  Result := IndexedProperty.IsDefault;
end;
```

How can I determine from a boolean function whether or not a property value from a component is the default or not?

Comment: Use a constant for the default value. Compare the value of the property to the constant. Assign the default value in the constructor.

Comment: @EProgrammer And if the component source is not yours? It doesn't look as though the asker knows what the component is at compile time.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan This is true, it could literally be any component. I have looked at the duplicate answer but I often value explanations over simple code answers so I will probably be best asking in a comment at that question. It's one thing having an asnwer to a duplicate question, but it does not satisfy my curiosity as to why my code failed above etc.

Comment: Step 1 is to debug your code. It seems entirely plausible that `IndexedProperty` is `nil`. Is the property really an indexed property? I'm sure that `Caption` is not. Of course, I cannot see the code you used to call your function. You did not provide an MCVE.